# Multiple Ranges paste into another sheet in order

Tags: vba, excel

Please help me with the following problem:
I have 3 ranges each on a different sheet.
I have to copy every range (till its last row with data and **paste values** with all of them on sheet "Rezultat" (in order so they will not paste on each other)

This is my code:

```
Sub MultipleRangesPaste()

Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range, MultipleRng As Range

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("REZULTAT")
    Set rng1 = Sheets("NEVOI PERSONALE").Range("F2:H" & Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    Set rng2 = Sheets("RATE").Range("F2:H" & Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    Set rng3 = Sheets("CARDURI").Range("G2:I" & Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

    Set MultipleRng = .Range(rng1 & rng2 & rng3) ' AT THIS LINE DEBUG SAID IT IS A PROBLEM
End With

MultipleRng.Copy
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("REZULTAT").Range("A2")
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
            SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use `application.Union`, but it doesn't work on multiple ranges from different worksheets. So in this case, you have to do it manually, copy>>paste each range, into the next available row.

```
Sub MultipleRangesPaste()

Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range, MultipleRng As Range
Dim NextRow As Long

Set rng1 = Sheets("NEVOI PERSONALE").Range("F2:H" & Sheets("NEVOI PERSONALE").Cells(Sheets("NEVOI PERSONALE").Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row)
Set rng2 = Sheets("RATE").Range("F2:H" & Sheets("RATE").Cells(Sheets("RATE").Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row)
Set rng3 = Sheets("CARDURI").Range("G2:I" & Sheets("CARDURI").Cells(Sheets("CARDURI").Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row)

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("REZULTAT")
    ' find current next empty row on Column A
    NextRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    rng1.Copy
    .Range("A" & NextRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
            SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            Application.CutCopyMode = False

    ' find current next empty row on Column A
    NextRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    rng2.Copy
    .Range("A" & NextRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
            SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            Application.CutCopyMode = False

    ' find current next empty row on Column A
    NextRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    rng3.Copy
    .Range("A" & NextRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
            SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly :) This will be good to know for the future also.

Answer (score 2):

My idea is pretty much as the one of @Shai Rado, but I did not write the whole code (that pleasure was intended for the OP) and I have a function, that locates the last used row, based on a column:

```
Option Explicit

Sub MultipleRangesPaste()

Dim rng1            As Range
Dim rng2            As Range
Dim rng3            As Range
Dim MultipleRng     As Range
Dim lngRowSource    As Long
Dim lngRowTarget    As Long
Dim lngRows         As Long

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("REZULTAT")
    Set rng1 = Sheets("NEVOI PERSONALE").Range("F2:H" & Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    Set rng2 = Sheets("RATE").Range("F2:H" & Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    Set rng3 = Sheets("CARDURI").Range("G2:I" & Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

End With

rng1.Copy
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("REZULTAT").Range("A2")
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
            SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
End With

rng2.Copy
'here locate the last row of column A in ThisWorkbook.Sheets("REZULTAT") and paste from there

rng3.Copy
'here locate the last row of column A in ThisWorkbook.Sheets("REZULTAT") and paste from there

End Sub

Public Function last_row(Optional str_sheet As String, Optional column_to_check As Long = 1) As Long

    Dim shSheet  As Worksheet

        If str_sheet = vbNullString Then
            Set shSheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
        Else
            Set shSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(str_sheet)
        End If

    last_row = shSheet.Cells(shSheet.Rows.Count, column_to_check).End(xlUp).Row

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and help.

Comment: Welcome. I hope you understood the idea of the `last_row` function.

Comment: @Vityata  nice, on the function, not sure it's necessary in this situation, but still nice